# validate form input from custom library in Codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a website where there are multiple form validation processes with the same ruleset. so I want to move the validation code into a single library file. but when I test it, the validation always fails.. why?

here's my code:

the library file:

```
<?php
/*
 * filename: My_validations.php
 * filedir: application/libraries/
 */
defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No direct script access allowed');

class My_validations
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci = &get_instance();
    }

    public function get_rules($params=[])
    {
        $rules = [];

        $module = $params['module'];

        if ($module == 'test')
        {
            $rules[] = [
                'field' => 'phone',
                'label' => 'test phone 1',
                'rules' => 'callback__test_rule1'
            ];
        }

        return $rules;
    }
    // end public function get_rules

    public function _test_rule1()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

the controller file:

```
<?php
/*
 * filename: test1.php
 * filedir: application/modules/test/controllers/
 */
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function test1()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->library('My_validations');

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
        {
            $params = [
                'module' => 'test',
            ];
            $rules = $this->my_validations->get_rules($params);
            echo 'rules <br>';
            print_r($rules);
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
            echo 'validate';
            $validate = $this->form_validation->run();
            echo '<pre>'.($validate ? 'OK' : 'failed').'</pre>'; // always 'failed'
        }
        $this->load->view('form', $this->data);
    }
}
```

and here's the form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" id="csrf" name="<?php echo $csrf_name; ?>" value="<?php echo $csrf; ?>">

        <div>
            <label>Phone</label>
            <input type="text" name="phone" value="<?php echo $this->input->post('phone'); ?>">
        </div>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Kirim">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does `$this->input->post('phone')` even work in the view?  I've never dared to try it; I always pass ALL data from the controller to the view.

Comment: @mickmackusa yes it does. I've been using that all this time and it works well. it's the same as using `$this->data['post'] = $_POST` in the controller and then `$post['phone']` in the view

Comment: It seem to be > the form validation callback will only fire on a method inside the current controller.
Relocate your function "_test_rule1" from "My_validations" to "Controller"

Answer (score 0):

The form validation callback will only fire on a method inside the current controller. Or extend CI_Form_validation class:

```
class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {
        
    function __constuct() {
        parent::__constuct();
    }

    public function get_rules($params=[])
    {
        $rules = [];

        $module = $params['module'];
        if ($module == 'test')
        {
            $rules[] = [
                'field' => 'phone',
                'label' => 'test phone 1',
                'rules' => '_test_rule1'
            ];
        }

        return $rules;
    }
    // end public function get_rules

    public function _test_rule1()
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to remove "callback_" prefix in rules.

After your corntroller will looks like:

```
<?php
/*
 * filename: test1.php
 * filedir: application/modules/test/controllers/
 */
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Test extends MY_Controller 
{
    public function test1()
    {
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //$this->load->library('My_validations');

        if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST')
        {
            $params = [
                'module' => 'test',
            ];
            //$rules = $this->my_validations->get_rules($params);
            $rules = $this->form_validation->get_rules($params);
            echo 'rules <br>';
            print_r($rules);
            $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);
            echo 'validate';
            $validate = $this->form_validation->run();
            echo '<pre>'.($validate ? 'OK' : 'failed').'</pre>'; // always 'failed'
        }
        $this->load->view('form', $this->data);
    }
}
```